# Why absolute positioned content inside div is cropped when height is lower than the content size?

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

@font-face {
    font-family: Pangolin;
    src: url("../Fonts/Pangolin.ttf");
}

* {
    font-family: Pangolin, serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, header{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.container-inner{
    min-height: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators, .carousel-inner, .carousel-item{
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner{
    overflow: visible;
}

.main-container-in-slider {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-container-in-slider h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 10px #333;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .main-container-in-slider h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
}

.carousel-item .background {
    height:100%;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(6px);
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover {
    background-color: #6e43bf;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    text-indent: initial;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1);
    margin: 5px;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-shadow: none;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}


.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    z-index: 2;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#first-carousel {
    min-height: auto;
}

.data-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95%;
}

.right {
    width: 100%;
}

#custom-controls-carousel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}


.video-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 14px;
}

.slider-caption {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider-text {
    max-width: 600px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.69);
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}


.fas {
    color: white;
}

.fas:hover {
    color: #eae7f7;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cst-line {
    width: 100px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ffca25;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .right {
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        min-width: 700px;
    }

    #custom-controls-carousel {
        bottom: 50px;
    }

    video {
        min-width: 700px;
    }

    .slider-caption {
        border-left: 5px solid #ffca25;
    }
}

.border-blue {
    border-left-color: #58aaff;
}

.border-green {
    border-left-color: #41ffa6;
}

.border-orange {
    border-left-color: #ff5a4b;
}

.border-purple {
    border-left-color: #8747ff;
}

.line-blue {
    background: #58aaff;
}

.line-green {
    background: #41ffa6;
}

.line-orange {
    background: #ff5a4b;
}

.line-purple {
    background: #8747ff;
}

.btn {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 99px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #333;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.btn-blue {
    background: #58aaff;
    border: 4px solid #5887ff;
}

.btn-green {
    background: #41ffa6;
    border: 4px solid #43ff96;
}

.btn-orange {
    background: #ff5a4b;
    border: 4px solid #ff2c37;
}

.btn-purple {
    background: #8747ff;
    border: 4px solid #8b50ff;

}

.btn-blue:hover {
    color: #58aaff;
    background-color: black;
}

.btn-green:hover {
    color: #41ffa6;
    background-color: black;
}

.btn-orange:hover {
    color: #ffca25;
    background-color: black;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
    color: #8747ff;
    background-color: black;
}

.fa-play-circle {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}

.fa-play-circle:hover {
    color: #e2e4ef;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 1000px) {
    .data-container{
        justify-content: start!important;
    }
}

.carousel{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/18e42a7034.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>SPŠIT | DOD</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators d-flex  ">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0">
                <span class="d-none d-md-block">
                    Informačné technológie
                </span>
                <i class="fas fa-server fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">
                  <span class="d-none d-md-block">
                    Elektrotechnika
                </span>
                <i class="fas fa-car-battery fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">
               <span class="d-none d-md-block">
                     Informačné a SieŤové technológie
                </span>
                <i class="fas fa-laptop fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3">
              <span class="d-none d-md-block">
                    Strojárstvo
                </span>
                <i class="fas fa-wrench fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
            </li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="background"
                     style="background-image: url('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.biamp.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F02%2Fvm_videocodecs_00-1024x681.jpg&f=1&nofb=1')">

                </div>
                <div class="data-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-xl-row align-items-center mt-3 mt-lg-2 p-2 p-md-4 p-lg-5">
                    <div class="left mr-0 mr-lg-4 mt-2 mt-xl-0 order-2 order-xl-1">
                        <h2 class="slider-caption border-orange text-center text-xl-left ">Informačné technológie</h2>
                        <div class="cst-line d-xl-none mx-auto line-orange"></div>
                        <p class="slider-text text-center text-xl-left p-x pt-2 p-xl-0">
                            Absolvent študijného odboru inteligentné technológie je kvalifikovaný odborný pracovník,
                            ktorý má vedomosti a zručnosti z oblasti informačných technológií, programovania,
                            počítačových sietí, smart technológií, internetu vecí, databázových systémov, základov
                            kybernetickej bezpečnosti, robotiky, 3D technológií, serverových a cloudových technológií,
                            grafiky, základov elektroniky, optimalizácie riadenia procesov a problematiky súvisiacej s
                            digitálnou firmou. Je schopný využívať mäkké zručnosti v prezentovaní a vystupovaní.
                        </p>
                        <div class="text-center text-xl-left">
                            <a href="http://www.spsknm.sk/ssknm/sk/inteligentne-technologie" target="_blank"
                               class="btn btn-orange">
                                <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>
                                Zistiť viac
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right order-1 order-xl-2">
                        <div class="video-container position-relative">
                            <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-4x position-absolute"></i>
                            <video>
                                <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="background"
                     style="background-image: url('assets/slider-electro.jpg')">

                </div>
                <div class="data-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-xl-row align-items-center mt-3 mt-lg-2 p-2 p-md-4 p-lg-5">
                    <div class="left mr-0 mr-lg-4 mt-2 mt-xl-0 order-2 order-xl-1">
                        <h2 class="slider-caption border-green text-center text-xl-left ">Elektrotechnika</h2>
                        <div class="cst-line d-xl-none mx-auto line-green"></div>
                        <p class="slider-text text-center text-xl-left p-x pt-2 p-xl-0">
                            Absolventi študijného odboru sú podľa zamerania pripravení na vykonávanie prác v oblasti
                            konštrukcie, výroby a prevádzky slaboprúdových zariadení, obsluhy, montáže, základnej údržby
                            výpočtovej techniky a počítačových sietí. V oblasti konštrukcie sú pripravení pracovať s
                            grafickým programovým systémom OrCAD 16, LaB VIEW, programujú v jazyku C. Navrhujú a
                            programujú riadiace systémy na báze jednočipových mikrokontrolérov rady AVR a PLC, vytvárajú
                            www stránky a iné internetové aplikácie. Absolventi budú vedieť využívať databázové systémy
                            a komunikovať v jednom svetovom jazyku.
                        </p>
                        <div class="text-center text-xl-left">
                            <a href="http://www.spsknm.sk/ssknm/sk/elektrotechnika" target="_blank"
                               class="btn btn-green">
                                <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>
                                Zistiť viac
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right order-1 order-xl-2">
                        <div class="video-container position-relative">
                            <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-4x position-absolute"></i>
                            <video>
                                <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="background"
                     style="background-image: url('assets/slider-ist2.jpg')">

                </div>
                <div class="data-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-xl-row align-items-center mt-3 mt-lg-2 p-2 p-md-4 p-lg-5">
                    <div class="left mr-0 mr-lg-4 mt-2 mt-xl-0 order-2 order-xl-1">
                        <h2 class="slider-caption border-blue text-center text-xl-left ">INFORMAČNÉ A SIEŤOVÉ
                            TECHNOLÓGIE</h2>
                        <div class="cst-line d-xl-none mx-auto line-blue"></div>
                        <p class="slider-text text-center text-xl-left p-x pt-2 p-xl-0">
                            Absolvent študijného odboru Informačné a sieťové technológie je kvalifikovaný zamestnanec
                            schopný samostatne vykonávať práce pri projektovaní, konštrukcii, výrobe, montáži, ako aj v
                            prevádzke a údržbe zariadení využívajúce moderné IT.
                            Pre kvalifikované vykonávanie uvedených činností získava absolvent štúdiom široký odborný
                            profil s nevyhnutným všeobecným vzdelaním, s dostatočnou adaptabilitou, logickým myslením a
                            schopnosťou aplikovať nadobudnuté vedomosti pri riešení problémov samostatne aj v tíme.
                        </p>
                        <div class="text-center text-xl-left">
                            <a href="http://www.spsknm.sk/ssknm/sk/informacne-a-sietove-technologie" target="_blank"
                               class="btn btn-blue">
                                <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>
                                Zistiť viac
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right order-1 order-xl-2">
                        <div class="video-container position-relative">
                            <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-4x position-absolute"></i>
                            <video>
                                <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="background"
                     style="background-image: url('assets/slider-engineer.jpg')">

                </div>
                <div class="data-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-xl-row align-items-center mt-3 mt-lg-2 p-2 p-md-4 p-lg-5">
                    <div class="left mr-0 mr-lg-4 mt-2 mt-xl-0 order-2 order-xl-1">
                        <h2 class="slider-caption border-purple text-center text-xl-left ">Strojártstvo</h2>
                        <div class="cst-line d-xl-none mx-auto line-purple"></div>
                        <p class="slider-text text-center text-xl-left p-x pt-2 p-xl-0">
                            Tento študijný odbor zaznamenal najväčšie zmeny, ktoré sa týkajú predovšetkým obsahu štúdia,
                            hlavne v posilnení zaradenia prác s výpočtovou technikou do všetkých štyroch ročníkov a
                            zaradenie predmetov z oblasti automobilovej konštrukcie a výroby v rámci výbornej spolupráce
                            s KIA Motors Slovakia. Absolventi študijného odboru sú pripravení pracovať v oblasti
                            konštrukcie s grafickým programovým systémom AutoCAD, Inventor a Pro/Engineer Wildfire. Sú
                            pripravení na vykonávanie prác v oblasti technickej prípravy, tvorby technických výkresov a
                            riadenia výroby pomocou počítačov, predovšetkým programovania počítačom riadených CNC
                            obrábacích strojov a v súvislosti s rozmachom automobilového priemyslu sa zaoberajú aj
                            konštrukciou automobilov. Sú pripravení na štúdium na vysokých školách hlavne technického
                            zamerania.
                        </p>
                        <div class="text-center text-xl-left">
                            <a href="http://www.spsknm.sk/ssknm/sk/strojarstvo" target="_blank" class="btn btn-purple">
                                <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>
                                Zistiť viac
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right order-1 order-xl-2">
                        <div class="video-container position-relative">
                            <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-4x position-absolute"></i>
                            <video source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>

            <a class="carousel-control-prev d-none d-xl-flex" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
               data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next d-none d-xl-flex" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
               data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
</header>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my issue is this:

My content inside my Carousel which is defined at 100% height is not dynamically  expanding when the content height is bigger then screen height. For example when height is 500px it is not enough for showing all my content on screen. But content is not scrollable but it is cropped like in overflow:hidden attribute. Why is this working like that and how to prevent this behaviour?

I think it is not necessary to put all my code here because it is only css and html. I have this on my own live server so I put only url here. If someone know I will be very thankful.

My link: https://younglocal.sk

here is image where you can see my content is not scrollable on low resolutions. It is getting cropped.
[image: My problem]

I can put there my css + html but as I wrote for analyze the problem it is not necessary when it is putted on live server... Thx

Comment: StackOverflow needs you to copy your code over here, because external links may not be reachable or you will have updated your site so people won't be able to get help from this post.

Comment: Ok i will put the ode here

Answer (score 0):

Since you shared only your link, I have solved it using inspect tool. Might not be accurate.

```
.carousel-item.active, .carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Nice this is exactly what i needed. Just one moore think what about that vlack buttons I would excepted they will be always on bottom of page.

Comment: @YoungL. Can you share your code properly? I don't understand what do you mean by vlack buttons

Comment: Ok screw it It is not working when i put here my code... don't know why

Comment: @YoungL. Help me understand, what is the problem with the black buttons?